# How can I implement JSplitPane.TOP and BOTTOM constanstants in when adding a JScrollPane to the JSplitPane?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, using, class-constants

I have two panels , one is `JTree` in a `JScrollPane` and the other is `JTable` in a `JScrollPane`. How can I place them in adjacent position using the `JSplitPane.TOP` and `JSplitPane.BOTTOM` constants so that they must equal space in the main panel?

Answer (score 0):

By using a `JSplitPane`, you can place one component above the other with `JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT`. Create your split pane like below:

```
splitPane = new JSplitPane (JSplitPane.VERTICAL_SPLIT, jtreeScrollPane, jtableScrollPane);
```

If you want to give them the same space, you can use:

```
splitPane.setResizeWeight (0.5);
```

Check the [How to Use Split Panes official tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html) for details.

---

You can also set a `GridLayout` as your `mainpanel's` layout in order to give your scrollpanes the same size.

If you want to put your scrollpanes one above the other you can set *2 rows* and *1 column*, if you want to align them horizontally you can use *1 row* and *2 columns*.

See the [How to use GridLayout tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for further details.

Comment: I have tried it. It didnt work. Finally I found one from a code segment